# make div (position:fixed) scroll horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this topic has been posted quite often already, but none of the solutions presented have been of any help to me by far. I have a sidebar on the left side of my page, which I assigned `position:fixed` in CSS, and which I would like to scroll horizontally (along with all the other content on my page)

For my header and footer I solved the issue like this:

```
 $(window).scroll(function ()
{
    $("header,footer").css('margin-left', -($(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
});
```

But this doesn't do it properly for my sidebar. 
This is the html for my sidebar:

```
<div class="fullscreen_block hided">
   <div class="left-sidebar-block">
```

and CSS:

```
.left-sidebar-block { 
position: fixed; 
margin-left: 70px;
}
```

Can anybody show me how I can fix this without using the above JS code? (any other JS or CSS or jQuery is fine)

Thanks!!

Comment: If you add the 70px to the above js code, is there still problems?

Comment: yeah, thats not it.. The problem with it is that it looks totally messy when I scroll horizontally, thats why I'm looking for an alternative

Comment: what if you use the `left` property instead of the `margin-left` property

Comment: same result! thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I think you want to use `scrollTop` instead of `scrollLeft`.  From your description, it sounds like you want to have an element slide to the left as the user scrolls down.  `scrollTop` will give you the distance the user has scrolled.

Second, I recommend using the `transform` property instead of the `margin` property, as long as it meets your browser support requirements. Scrolling tricks are often performance intensive so you should try to use high performance css properties like `transform` and `opacity` rather than slower properties like `margin`, `left`, and `display`.

The following code does what I think you are trying to do. (Codepen demo: http://codepen.io/regdoug/pen/yyYvaV):

```
$(window).scroll(function ()
{
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("left-sidebar-block").css('transform', 'translateX(' + (-top) + "px)")
                      .css('-ms-transform', 'translateX(' + (-top) + "px)")
                      .css('-webkit-transform', 'translateX(' + (-top) + "px)");
});
```

References

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/scrolling/

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/

http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the code you posted doesn't have any effect on my website (in Safari)...

Comment: thanks! using your updated code with "scrollLeft" did exactly what I wanted it to do! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not really clear.. but I think you shoukd better play with the "left" attribute rather than "margin-left". Margins won't have any effect on a fixed element..